# fullPage.js: Make all slides and sections visible in search engine results

Tags: jquery, seo, web-crawler, single-page-application, fullpage.js

I'm using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) jQuery plugin for a Single page application.

I'm using mostly default settings and the plugin works like a charm.
When I got to the SEO though I couldn't properly make Google crawl my website on a "per slide" basis.

All my slides are loaded at the page load so ajax is not even an issue, but GoogleBot doesn't seem to be able to visualize each slide as a page (I presume because all the html content is always loaded and can't tell apart the various slides)

Is there a way to make GoogleBot understand that each "/#Section/Slide" is a different page and should have a different result in the search engine? Maybe with microdata or any other semantic workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't be able to force Google to index your anchor links as different pages. You will be able to index them as a single page.
Google will read your page as what it really is. A single page.

[There are some recommendations](http://searchengineland.com/single-page-websites-seo-182506) which suggest to use the `id` tag to separate content. But the problem with this is that it won't work in fullPage.js as fullPage.js doesn't allow to use the same `id` value as for your `anchor` links.

This way, if you use a different value, google might index the `id` element which will cause fullPage.js to break once you access to the link.

I believe that as much as you can do is using `section` elements like so:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <section>1st section</section>
    <section>2nd section</section>
    <section>3rd section</section>
</div>
```

And initialize fullpage.js using the sectionSelector` option like so:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionSelector: 'section'
});
```

And as suggested in the previous link, use `h1` elements inside each section.

You can also take a look at this video from Google regarding [single page websites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mibrj2bOFCU). But I would suggest just to try and test it yourself with some single pages you might now, for example the main [fullPage.js website](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). 
Look for portions of text displayed in different sections or slides and you'll find out how Google indexes them without any problem although the indexed link won't contain the anchor link.

Comment: so dynamically change the title via php and different url parameters in the sitemap is the only viable way to differenciate search results? I'm doing this by also changing the landing slide with each url

Comment: It is difficult for google to index your anchored pages **separately**. Just look at the main fullPage.js site in google and you'll notice its anchor links are not indexed as different pages. And that's a page with lots of visits. But if you look for any text inside those slides or sections you'll find the result in google. So, it is indexed, but as a single page.

Comment: Your sections and slides will be indexed in any case, but as a single page. Not as separate pages of your site.

Comment: So even putting different urls with different parameters (like http://example.com?section=1&slide=5) in the sitemap would work?

Comment: @Mike the thing is fullPage.js doesn't work that way. And even if it did, you still loading a whole site when accessing that link. It might be considered duplicated content.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by adding a parameter to your main URL for each slide. If the URL is called with parameter value 1, the first slide is displayed, with 2, slide 2, etc...

Then add each URL combination in your sitemap.xml.

Comment: Interesting approach, and since all my content is present in the page no matter the parameters, to differenciate the results on the search engine is it enough to dynamically change the page title?

Comment: No. You need different URLs. If you don't use different titles, you may get an improvement recommendation message in GWT. Google may also craft its own titles for you.

Comment: Ok ok, I meant on top of the different url (parameters) if I can do anything else like changing the title to characterize the single pages since the actual html dom and content are very similar to each other in all the pages. As I said the website is all loaded on access and doesn't have dynamically changing content

Comment: Setting unique and relevant titles per URLs is always better. You can include keywords, but it must remain natural for the human reader. Warning: Google does search for keyword stuffing in titles.